# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.10

Tags: vb.net

while using the given below code showing one error. The error is : `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.` Help me to find a proper solution. thank you.

Code:

```
 cmd1 = con1.CreateCommand
 cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * from staff_profile where staff_id='" + STFID + "'"
 sdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader
 If sdr1.Read = True Then
   'Image1.ImageUrl = sdr1("photo_url")
    Dim N1, N2, N3 As String
    N1 = sdr1("first_name")
    N2 = sdr1("middle_name")
    N3 = sdr1("last_name")
    Label15.Text = N1 + " " + N2 + "" + N3
    Label16.Text = sdr1("designation")
    Label17.Text = sdr1("department")
    Label18.Text = sdr1("date_of_birth")
    Label19.Text = sdr1("age")
    Label20.Text = sdr1("father_name")
    Label21.Text = sdr1("permanant_address")
    Label23.Text = sdr1("mobile")
    Label26.Text = sdr1("dateofjoin")     
End If
sdr1.Close()
con1.Close()
```

Error Screen:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the middle_name available or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
N2 = sdr1("middle_name").ToString()
```

or you can first check if it is not null like this:

```
If Not IsDBNull(sdr1("middle_name")) Then
    N2 = sdr1("middle_name")
End If
```

Comment: The [`DBNull.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t(v=vs.110).aspx) form will result in an empty string, which is neither null (.NET) nor NULL (SQL).